# stack (in groupoids) over a site $\mathcal{C}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, stacks

Question : What is a stack (in groupoids) over a site $\mathcal{C}$ for you?

There are two a ways to think about it.

1. A stack over a site $\mathcal{C}$ is a category $\mathcal{D}$ with a functor $\pi_{\mathcal{D}}:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ satisfying some conditions.
2. A stack over a site $\mathcal{C}$ is a “functor” $\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow (Gpd)$ satisfying some conditions.

Was there a situation where thinking of stacks in one way is easier/more enlightening in some sense than the other way? This of course  depend on what one wants to do. I want to collect situations and explanations of where and how thinking of stacks was easier/enlightening.